# warning: 'UIWindow' may not respond to '-addSubView:'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am just trying to write my  very first code in Objective C.

I have created a new project in XCode and added the following lines of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UILabel *myMessage;
    myMessage=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 300, 500, 75)];
    myMessage.text=@"Hello World!";
    myMessage.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:72];
    [window addSubView:myMessage];
    [myMessage release];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

However, I got the following warning (on line [window addSubView:myMessage]):

warning: 'UIWindow' may not respond to '-addSubView:'

And when I launch the application, it just terminates.

Though I just copied the code from the book "Sams Teach Yourself iPad Development", and it seems that it should show a message on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get rid of the capital V. it should be

```
[window addSubview:myMessage];
```

Comment: But why on Earth didn't the compiler issue an error? Why was it just a warning?

Comment: it could be a method that hasn't been defined in your version of the header, and in obj-c classes can be modified at runtime, so just because it isn't documented doesn't mean it isn't there. its to allow you to call a method it isn't aware of, if you know its there.